# how to make lodash work with angular4 aot

Tags: angular, lodash, angular2-aot

What is the correct way to import lodash with systemjs.config.js. 
My AOT is failing due to lodash.
My project is a component library based on https://github.com/filipesilva/angular-quickstart-lib

> I am using in package.json 
>   "lodash": "4.17.4"
>    and  "@types/lodash": "4.14.68"

Following is my systemjs.config.js

````
```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
        'primeng': 'npm:primeng',

        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'angular-quickstart-lib': 'npm:angular-quickstart-lib/bundles/angular-quickstart-lib.umd.js',
        'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
          meta: {
              './*.js': {
                  loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
              }
          }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
        'primeng': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'angular-quickstart-lib': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            meta: {
                './*.js': {
                    loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
                }
            }
        },
        'lodash':{
          main: 'index.js',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
  });
})(this);

```
````

I am importing lodash as follows

`import * as _ from 'lodash';`

But while AOT I am getting following error.

`(node:5810) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: 'cloneDeep' is not exported by node_modules/lodash/lodash.js
(node:5810) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you got your configuration mapping wrong for lodash, instead of this:

`'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js'`
it should of been:
`'lodash': 'npm:lodash/index.js'`

This is what inside index.js

`module.exports = require('./lodash');`